# joomla ACL :: two groups permissions conflict

Tags: joomla

I have several user groups on my website, like:

- Site Staff
- Departments
- -- History department
- -- Physics department
- -- Foreign languages department
- -- IT department etc

I also have several categories, like:

- News
- About
- ...
- Departments

  - -- History department
  - -- Physics department
  - -- Foreign languages department
  - -- IT department etc

Users in **Site Staff** group can edit entire site, except for **Departments** categories (I've set **Deny** permission for it). Each Department user group can edit only its corresponding category.

I have successfully implemented all this.

The question is:
If a user belongs to two groups (**Site Staff** and **Physics department** - for instance) - he should be able to edit the whole site, except for Departments category. **And also he should be able to edit *Physics department* category** - this is what I cannot implement.

Can you suggest any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved that ( created another parent category for all but Departments).